# Query with joins with temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join, common-table-expression

I have the following query:

```
select vkbr.vkID, vkbr.bid, vkbr.Date, vkbr.agID 
FROM camp c (NOLOCK)
JOIN    ag (NOLOCK) ON ag.campID = c.id
JOIN    vkbr WITH (NOLOCK) ON vkbr.agID = ag.id
where c.id = 648322
order by vkbr.vkID;
```

Which has the following results:

```
vkID        bid     Date                    agID
1072845175  NULL    2012-12-04 20:20:12.390 16074852
1072845177  0.74    2012-12-01 23:36:11.280 16074852
1072845177  0.18    2012-12-02 23:01:26.123 16074852
1072845177  0.72    2012-12-09 23:38:52.503 16074852
1072845177  0.62    2012-12-14 15:26:49.643 16074852
1072845178  2.91    2012-12-08 19:37:00.877 16074852
1072845178  0.73    2012-12-13 17:54:11.240 16074852
1072845178  2.70    2012-12-14 15:26:49.643 16074852
```

In order to return the following rows, I use cte and then SELECT :

```
1072845175  NULL    2012-12-04 20:20:12.390 16074852
1072845177  0.62    2012-12-14 15:26:49.643 16074852
1072845178  2.70    2012-12-14 15:26:49.643 16074852

with cte as
(    
select vkbr.vkID, vkbr.bid, vkbr.Date, vkbr.agID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY     vkbr.vkID ORDER BY vkbr.Date DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM camp c (NOLOCK)
JOIN ag (NOLOCK) ON ag.campID = c.id
JOIN vkbr WITH (NOLOCK) ON vkbr.agID = ag.id
where c.id = 648322
)

select vkID, bid, Date, agID
from cte
where RowNumber = 1
```

I need to get bid from cte and insert it into an existing temp table called #t:

```
insert into #t (bid)    
select bid
from cte
where RowNumber = 1
and #t.Date = cte.Date
and #t.agId = cte.agId
and #t.vkId = cte.vkID;
```

I need to have those joins with #t in order to make sure I insert the right bid for the right row; but I receive this error:

"The multi-part identifier "#t.date" cound not be bound."

I was thinking to create another temp table, insert the rows from cte into that temp table and then have joins with #t. Is there any other solution to do this w/o creating a temp table? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you're inserting into `#t`, it is out of the scope of your `select` statement... try joining to the same table that you're inserting into to perform this filtering:

```
insert into #t (bid)    
select cte.bid
from cte 
join #t 
  on #t.Date = cte.Date
  and #t.agId = cte.agId
  and #t.vkId = cte.vkID;
where cte.RowNumber = 1
```

However, are you sure that you're wanting to perform an `insert` instead of an `update`?

```
update t
set t.bid = cte.bid
from cte 
join #t t 
  on t.Date = cte.Date
  and t.agId = cte.agId
  and t.vkId = cte.vkID;
where cte.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: are you on a chat room :) ? Gotta ask something on a `regexp`

Comment: @blueSky not you, sorry it's for Michael ;)

Comment: @Michael: I just got what you mean by INSERT and UPDATE after receiving the sql error!!! Its in fact an UPDATE! Thanks for pointing that out :-)